# Passing data between activities

Tags: java, android

My main activity contains a EditText and a button. 
I would like to send whats written in the EditText to the next activity started by pressing the button.

In the first activity I have this:

```
        Intent i = new Intent(firstActivity.this, secondActivity.class);  
        i.putExtra("myString", theEditText.getText());
        startActivity(i);
```

So far so good. In the second activity I use this:

```
  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras(); 
  myRecivedString = bundle.getString("myString")
```

But here myRecivedString turns up empty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: First thing I would do is `Log.d("yourTag", theEditText.getText());` and see if that's got content at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `theEditText.getText().toString();`. You are able to get the text written in `edittext`.

Comment: That did it! Super thanks! I love this Stackoverflow. Answers superquick!

Answer (score 2):

See getText() method of [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) returns object of [Editable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html) class.
So if you want to pass the string contained in EditText, you have to use toString().

See the example here :

```
 thisEditText.getText().toString();
```

So the code in your first activity should look like :

```
 Intent i = new Intent(firstActivity.this, secondActivity.class);  
 i.putExtra("myString", theEditText.getText().toString());
 startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Yep! That was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change `i.putExtra("myString", theEditText.getText());` to `i.putExtra("myString", theEditText.getText().toString())`;